# Packetfence blocks the network environment

Tags: networking, open-source, 802.1x

I am new to the open source network access control solution called [Packetfence](http://www.packetfence.org/).

I am currently diagnosing Packetfence log files remotely.

The network seemed to be running smoothly with Packetfence, until around the 5th-6th of March. Now, when the Packetfence service is started, the network on the destination stops working.

There are 50+ switches and 500+ PCs and devices that access the network so it is not possible to diagnose this issue in other ways than looking at log files.

Some errors from the log file:

- > `Mar 05 17:14:34 pfsetvlan(22) ERROR: error creating SNMP v2c read connection to 172.17.250.19: No response from remote host '172.17.250.19' (pf::SNMP::connectRead)`
- > `ERROR: could not convert dot1dBasePort into ifIndex in any VLAN. Setting trapType to unknown (pf::SNMP::Cisco::parseTrap)`
- > `Mar 06 08:41:01 pfsetvlan(5) INFO: mac trap received on 172.17.250.90 ifindex 11 which is uplink and we don't manage uplinks (pf::vlan::doWeActOnThisTrap)`
- > `INFO: doWeActOnThisTrap returns false. Stop mac handling (main::handleTrap)`
- > `Mar 06 08:41:04 pfdhcplistener(3617) INFO: could not resolve 172.17.4.120 to mac in ARP table (pf::iplog::ip2macinarp)`

1. Why do these error messages occur?
2. What can I do to continue searching for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is the one you should focus on. Most of the operations in PacketFence require proper SNMP access and failure to create a proper read connection will propagate failures to the other components.

You can troubleshoot your SNMP reads with something like:

```
/usr/local/pf/bin/pfcmd_vlan -switch 10.0.0.15 -getAlias -ifIndex 12 -verbose 4
```

You could also troubleshoot with snmpwalk directly:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community> 10.0.0.15 IF-MIB::ifAlias
```

Most likely causes:

- wrong SNMP read / write community configured on switch
- wrong SNMP read / write community configured in PacketFence's switches.conf
- no route to the switch's management IP (IP configured in switches.conf)
- firewall in between PacketFence and switch blocking the traffic

Note: Wrong community string will behave exactly as if you can't reach the switch. This is how SNMP was designed.

Comment: i executed the above command with my switch ip but displays nothing. plus there is no firewall ,iptables or SE Linux enabled on machine.

Comment: @ oliveir, one more thing the switches.conf file does not have the normal vlan community string which is 10.

Comment: There could still be ACLs or firewall elsewhere between the server and your switches.

Comment: @AhmedSaad, `normalVlan` and community string are two different concepts. Don't mix them up. `normalVlan` has nothing to do with your current problem. Community strings are defined with the following two parameters in `switches.conf` under SNMP version 1 or 2c (SNMPv3 configuration differs): `SNMPCommunityRead` and `SNMPCommunityWrite`.